# Error en login de Laravel en navbar hecho con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, laravel, login

Tengo un navbar que hice con bootstrap para que cualquiera pueda logear en cualquier parte de la aplicación en el navbar pero tengo un error que me está volviendo loco y es que no me deja logear con dropdown que hice para el login y le doy al botón y no envía el formulario y si coloco login por fuera del dropdown (destruyendo así el diseño del navbar) si ejecuta el login ahora esto me parece algo sumamente extraño un dropdown no debería poder afectar el login (es como si el botón no funcionara).

Aqui el codigo que tengo en mi navba, el include llama el view login donde tengo mi vista de login separada

```
  @if (Auth::guest())
                          @include('shared.nlogin')
                      @else
                          <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                  {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                              </a>

                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                          onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                          Logout
                                      </a>

                                      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                                      </form>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                      @endif
```

Esta es mi vista de login con su formulario y el dropdown.

```
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <strong class="caret"></strong></a> 

  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
    <div class="">
      <input id="email" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="email" name="user[username]" size="30" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus/>
      @if ($errors->has('email'))
          <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
          </span>
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="">
        <input id="password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" required size="30" class="form-control"/>
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"  style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me </label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" />
    <input class="btn btn-danger" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; margin-top:5px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Registrarse" onclick="location.href='{{ url('/register') }}';" />
</form> </div> </li>
```

Me parece algo muy extraño que un simple dropdown haga que no pueda logear.

Resumen del problema : en pocas palabras si saco el el li y el div que contienen el drowpdown funciona perfectamente el login pero destruye el navbar que hice